# How add a reference at the end of reference list?

Tags: citing

In an article of mine, the author–number citation style (aka. Vancouver system) is applied, which

> uses numbers within the text that refer to numbered entries in the reference list

(quotation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vancouver_system))

When I compile the TeX-related files of the article, the number assigned to each citation is determined by the order of appearance of that citation in the article. I'm going to insert some new citations in the article. But I'd like to add them at the end of the reference list so that the assigned numbers to the already-present references don't change. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of LaTeX's automatic bibliography solutions (BibTeX and `biblatex`) is that you don't have to worry about formatting and sorting your bibliography: Everything is sorted according to well defined scheme.

The 'problem' with that is that it is not simple to deviate from the sort order. So **I strongly recommend you accept that the bibliography numbers might change when you add or remove sources: That's rather the point.**

In theory there are some ways you could stop BibTeX from sorting your bibliography correctly. But that would require manual intervention or different cite commands, which in my opinion rather defeats the purpose of LaTeX's citation and bibliography handling. Anyway, here are two ideas.

### `thebibliography`

When you compile a document like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
lorem \cite{inbook-full}
ipsum \cite{article-full}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX. BibTeX writes the ready-to-typeset bibliography into the `.bbl` file, LaTeX then just reads that file and typesets the bibliography.

If you now want to append another citation at the end of the bibliography even though it may be cited anywhere, you can just copy the contents of the `.bbl` file to where `\bibliography` is in your document and manually add your citation entries at the end

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
lorem \cite{order}

lorem \cite{inbook-full}
ipsum \cite{article-full}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} \newcommand{\printfirst}[2]{#1}
  \newcommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1} \newcommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{inbook-full}
Donald~E. Knuth.
\newblock {\em Fundamental Algorithms}, volume~1 of {\em The Art of Computer
  Programming}, section 1.2, pages 10--119.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, second edition, 10~January
  {\noopsort{1973b}}1973.
\newblock This is a full INBOOK entry.

\bibitem{article-full}
L[eslie]~A. Aamport.
\newblock The gnats and gnus document preparation system.
\newblock {\em \mbox{G-Animal's} Journal}, 41(7):73+, July 1986.
\newblock This is a full ARTICLE entry.

\bibitem{order}
Ann Elk.
\newblock A Theory on Brontosauruses.
\newblock 1972.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

You can essentially fully control the sorting by moving around the entries in `thebibliography`. The disadvantage is that you have to manually create the entries for the new sources you cite (of course they can be obtained by running BibTeX as normal on a different document).

### 'Automatic' solution with a new cite command

The following solution creates a new citation command `\defercite` whose citations will be added to the end of the bibliography (in the order they appear in the text).

It works by not sending the cite request to the `.aux` file when the source is cited but by adding it to a list and writing the cite requests out at the end of the document.

(*NB* This MWE assumes the standard definition of `\cite` from the LaTeX kernel, because there was no MWE in the question and no hint that a different package such as `cite` or `natbib` might be used. If you are loading one of those packages, a different definition might be needed.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\defercitelist}{}

\DeclareRobustCommand\defercite{%
  \@ifnextchar [{\@tempswatrue\@defercitex}{\@tempswafalse\@defercitex[]}}
\def\@defercitex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \listxadd{\defercitelist}{\@citeb}%
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}

\newcommand*{\citeunsort@writecitation}[1]{%
  \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{#1}}\fi}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \forlistloop{\citeunsort@writecitation}{\defercitelist}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
order \defercite{incollection-full}

lorem \cite{inbook-full}
ipsum \cite{article-full}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

If you want full control over the sorting instead, remove the `\AtEndDocument` block and add

```
\nocite{<new key 1>,<new key 2>, ..., <new key n>}
```

at the end after the `\bibliography` call in the order you want the entries to appear in the bibliography.